# Component lazy loading in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lazy-loading

I'm actually trying to build an app with React-Native with Expo, and try to lazyload some components with React.lazy() but I always end up with error message:

`Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.
Check the render method of App.`

Here is a really basic example of how I'm doing it (just react here): https://repl.it/@projer/component-lazy-loading

Comment: https://medium.com/react-native-training/lazy-bundle-loading-in-react-native-5f717b65482a

Comment: have you tried with an HOC as an async component? https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/loading-components-asynchronously-in-react-app-with-an-hoc-61ca27c4fda7

Comment: @JulianTorregrosa I have exactly the same error message : Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.